# Java count all the values of an array and store it in another variable (array/map/list)

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

I have a string array. I want to count values of that array. In PHP I did so using `print_r(array_count_values($a))`. It printed `Array ( [A] => 2 [Cat] => 1 [Dog] => 2 )`.

Now this time `wfBlocks` containing `[1469441140125, 1469441140125, 1469441140125,1469441126299, 1469441126299]`. I apply the following code, it works.

```
 Map<String, String[]> map = request.getParameterMap();
    String[] wfBlockIds     = map.get("wf_block_id[]");
            Arrays.stream(wfBlockIds)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
              .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k+" => "+v.size() + " --" + v));
```

Output:

```
1469441140125 => 3 --[1469441140125, 1469441140125, 1469441140125]
1469441126299 => 2 --[1469441126299, 1469441126299]
```

I have another variable called `stepCounter`. The int `stepCounter` will be incremented and after reaching to new array's size. It will print `0,1,2` for `1469441140125 => 3 --[1469441140125, 1469441140125, 1469441140125]` and `0,1` for `1469441126299 => 2 --[1469441126299, 1469441126299]`

How to set `[1469441140125, 1469441140125, 1469441140125]` into an array and 
`[1469441126299, 1469441126299]` into another array. `stepCounter` will be 0 for each array. NB: These arrays are part of `wfBlocks`.

Comment: I dont get your question. Maybe you should start "conservative"; whats wrong with writing down a simple for list, parsing each string to a number; and to simply sum them up?And the second part; I have absolutely no clue what you mean there.

Comment: I am asking to set the output of  Arrays.stream(wfBlockIds)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
              .forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k+" => "+v.size() + " --" + v)); into a Map or variable.

Comment: Doesn't map already holds the values? Not sure what you are trying to do here...

Comment: Never put more infos into comments. Update your question instead!

Comment: You have rejected my edit. Well, at least include "java-8" in the tags. It's the version of java that you are using. It will do no harm and maybe will improve your question visibility.